# How can I split the headers of data and the data itself to their own respective columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a file that has `312759` rows but only one column with different header names in the one row, so I need to separate that rows with their own values and columns. So the data frame has `312759 rows × 1 columns` but I need `312759 X approx. 40 headers/cols`. I am new python and to stackoverflow community so any help would be appreciated.

[image: screenshot of raw csv file dataset]

Answer (score 0):

read the data using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

read = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
read.drop(read.head(5).index, inplace=True)

then save it back as a .csv file
read.to_csv("output2.csv")
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-10-8e7d3d348dee>", line 2
    read.to_csv("output2.csv')
                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal                                                               
                                                                                                                                       I get this error when i try to save it back as a .csv

Comment: yea thanks for pointing that out but that method actually ends up dropping the headers which I don't want. Please take a look at the screenshot again. I want to retain the data and col headers but remove the descriptors i.e. Report Name, Start Date, Pre-Run Filters, Note. (take a look at screenshot link). After that I want to be able to split the headers and the data itself to their own respective columns. does that make sense?

Comment: when i use excel to open the raw csv file:                                                                              1. choose delimited and file origin (Windows - ANSI) 2. set delimiter as comma then the csv opens up with headers and data in their respective columns. how do i accomplish this in python? any help would be appreciated.